# Install private key / certificate / keystore support

Tags: certificate, install4j, keytool

[Install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) is an very versatile installer builder. I'm interested in finding out if it can be used to configure and install a server-sided certificate (possibly through java keystore/keytool interaction). Such a certificate would be used by the application that is being installed by Install4j (which, in my case, is a web server that is to be accessed over HTTPS).

In Install4j's documentation, most references to 'certificate' that I come across relate to code signing functionality. A worthwhile feature, but different from the one that I'm currently interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 10, there are no specific actions for Java keystore modifications.

You would have to call the [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html) command line tool in the JRE with "Run executable or batch file" actions to install a certificate into the Java keystore.